# Object de uma classe em outra classe Java

Tags: java, classes, objetos, instanciar-objeto

Olá,

Há possibilidade de ter o object da classe que instanciou na classe instanciada?

Ex.:

- (Sintaxe incorreta, apenas uma suposição)

  ```
   public class Classe2 {

    // Metodos e vetores da classe
   }
  ```

Instância da **Classe2** na **Classe1** com o objeto:

```
public class Classe1 {
      public static void main(Object classe){
         Classe2 classe = new Classe2(Classe1); // Aqui passando o object da classe como parâmetro.
      }
   }
```

Na **Classe2** preciso dos métodos de retorno da **Classe1**, preciso disso no momento da instância da **Classe1**.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que você quer algo assim:

```
public class Classe2 {

    private String nome;

    public Classe2(Classe1 classe1) {
        this.nome = classe1.getNome();
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

E

```
Classe1 classe1 = new Classe1();
classe1.setNome("teste");
Classe2 classe2 = new Classe2(classe1);
classe2.getNome(); // teste
```

Como você não disse qual o propósito, não sei te falar qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você queira algo assim:

```java
public class Criatura {

    private Criador criador;

    public Criatura(Criador criador) {
        this.criador = criador;
    }

    public Criador getCriador() {
        return criador;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Criador {
    public Criatura criar() {
        return new Criatura(this);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Criador pai = new Criador();

        // Esta é uma forma de se criar o objeto.
        Criatura filho1 = pai.criar();

        // Esta é uma outra forma de criar o objeto.
        Criatura filho2 = new Criatura(pai);
    }
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, duas formas de criar o objeto da classe, muito obrigado!